# How do I figure out who has a SQL Server 2005 database in Single User Mode?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database in single user mode and I am trying to drop it so I can re-run the creation scripts on it, but I'm being locked out from it.

1. How do I figure out who has the lock on it?
2. How do I disable that lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run sp_who, find the spid with the database name you require, kill the spid.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server Management Studio:

1. open the object explorer
2. expand the database server
3. expand "Management"
4. double-click on "Activity Monitor"
5. locate the process using the desired database
6. right-click on process
7. click "Kill Process"